# How do I bind a bunyan logging function to a class function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, ecmascript-6, bunyan

Fussing with this one a bit today, still getting an error. [Docs here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) Closest I have is this:

```
constructor(region, sslEnabled = true, 
     logger = () => {}, errorLogger = () => {}) {
if (region === undefined || !region)
  throw new Error("Initialization error: region is required");

  this.log = () => {};           // these two lines might be unnecessary
  this.logError = () => {};      //
  this.log = logger.bind(this);
  this.logError = errorLogger.bind(this);
  this.region = region;
  this.sslEnabled = sslEnabled;
}
```

Elsewhere in the class I send a bunyan logger's functions in:

```
const tools = new Tools(
  config.region,
  config.ssl,
  logger.debug,
  logger.error
);
```

The logger is just using console output. This works if I pass `console.log` and `console.error` but fails if I pass Bunyan loggers:

```
bunyan usage error: /usr/src/app/src/healthcheck.js:47: 
 attempt to log with an unbound log method: `this` is: TTools {
  log: [Function: bound ],
  logError: [Function: bound ],
  region: 'us-west-2',
  sslEnabled: false }
```

There is a github issue about this but it didn't really make it clear how to fix it. How do I pass a bunyan logger function like `logger.error` to another object? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its complaining about `this` then that's because the `this` context is lost when you send `logger.debug` function.

Use ES6 fat arrow function to get around this problem.

```
const tools = new Tools(
  config.region,
  config.ssl,
  x => logger.debug(x),
  x => logger.error(x)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbound object methods should never be passed as callbacks if they are expected to be bound to their context. It is possible to pass `console` methods as callbacks because they are bound to `console` in *most* modern implementations, but this should never be implied in cross-platform code.

`console` methods are already bound to `console` in Node.js and can be safely passed as callbacks without additional measures.

For other methods, it should be:

```
const tools = new Tools(
  config.region,
  config.ssl,
  logger.debug.bind(logger),
  logger.error.bind(logger)
);
```